# Unable to find sys/fdio.h (floppy disk control operations) on Solaris machine 5.11

Tags: c, include, solaris

I am compiling my application code on Solaris 5.11, Code is written in C.In the application code I used "fdio" related code. The Solaris box do not have that . How to get the sys/fdio package.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/fdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World");
}
```

"test1.c", line 2: cannot find include file:

Comment: Weird https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/solaris-opensolaris-20/unable-to-find-fdio-floppy-disk-control-operations-on-solaris-machine-5-11-11-4-0-15-0-a-4175658332/

Comment: Can you just remove the #include?  Does your application really need to interact directly with floppy disks still?  (If so, you have bigger problems as Solaris 11 doesn't support the floppy controller any more.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is no longer available in Solaris 11. [Here is a copy](https://github.com/openzfs/openzfs/blob/master/usr/src/uts/common/sys/fdio.h) that will help you compile your code. Drop it in `/usr/include/sys` It is opensource so there should be a few copies out there.

Comment: That will get past the compile stage, but the program will then use library calls that don't exist, so it won't link.

Comment: @andrewHenle If you checked the header you will see it only defines data structures and constants. It will link and run without any problem.

Comment: Thanks Gerhard. I will give a try by adding fdio.h